# Spyder Autocomplete Not Working

Tags: python, autocomplete, editor, spyder

I use python 3.5 with anaconda and spyder IDE. I have a problem with autocomplete:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

myList = [i for i in range(10)];

pdDataframe = pd.DataFrame(myList)

npArray = np.array(myList, dtype = int)
```

If I type npArray. plus tab on the IPython console a list with attributes (functions) appears. But when I type npArray. plus tab on the spyder editor nothing happens. The autocomplete feature is working on the spyder editon for variable names, numpy functions, pandas dataframes, python lists and is enabled on the preferences.

For example np. plus tab, myList. plus tab, pd.Dataframe. plus tab is OK. The problem occurs only with numpy arrays on the spyder editor. How can I fix it?

Comment: I am not sure how to fix it, but I notice it as follows.  If I type "np.array" I don't get the auto complete, but if type "np.array(" it shows up.