# Spyder display balloon tips and code auto completion not working in Anaconda Navigator Mac OS Sierra

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, macos-sierra

Spyder v.3.1.3 balloon tips and autocomplete are not working despite being enabled.  Utilizing Spyder with Python v.3.5.2 in Anaconda Navigator v.1.4.3 on MacOS Sierra.  I have attempted multiple reboots, and disabled / re-enabled the features.  Initially these weren't working on an earlier version of Spyder and then I upgraded and they worked briefly.

Any insight as to what is causing this issue and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

I have perused a few other threads, but no definitive answers

[Spyder Autocomplete Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978245/spyder-autocomplete-not-working) - outlines almost exact same problem, but no solution.  Also I am not using IPython or any external packages, just the native python 3 modules.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2162

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder developer here*) Unfortunately, there are objects that can't be code-completed in the Spyder Editor. It's not an installation problem nor anything users can solve on their side, just a limitation of the libraries we use to get and display completions.

A draft of a solution is proposed on the issue you referenced, we just need to find the time to do it.

Comment: Carlos, thank you for the update.  However, I should elaborate.  My professor is receiving code completion and tool tips on his demonstrations (live) and my system is not giving me the same completions / tips.  This leads me to believe it is something particular to my installation.

Comment: Please post a simple code example as part of your question so I can take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Carlos,  here is a simple example:  pointsInaGame = [0, -10, 15, -2, 1, 12]
sortedGame = sorted(pointsInaGame)
print(sorted).  Where Spyder should suggest the variable the second time I type it and it should also suggest sorted by the time I have typed sort.  This does not happen.

Comment: You need to press the `Tab` key to get those completions. It doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: Even with tabbing, it doesn't always work.  Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot this?

Comment: It depends on your code. But for the simple code you posted, it should work all the time.